# PostInstall script execution failed packagekmaker

Tags: macos, packagemaker, pkgbuild

I have PostInstall Script Named postinstall. I have added in Post install section.When I try to build it it build successfully but with warning "User 504 does not match 502 of root volume for /Library/Internet Plug-Ins...make sure to have disk permission repaired with disk utility" and run the package it show that Installation Failed.

I repaired the package after that also I am getting message Installation failed message.I checked the log an got following message
PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “MyTestApp”."

I have tried with permission as well but its not working.I am using OSX 10.7 and Package Maker 3.0.5
PLease help me.

// postinstall script

## !/bin/sh

echo "My Scripts"
exit 0

Steps I am doing

On Terminal

Step 1    vi postinstall
Step 2    add shell script code
Step 3    save and exit the file
Step 4    "chmod +x postinstall"
Step 5    Add the script and build

Comment: I doubt that "echo" line is your real postinstall script. What does your script look like, and what is it trying to do?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I am testing with those line.even with those line it is not working.Not sure is there any script file naming issue??

Comment: if you take the postinstall script out (temporarily), do you get a successful install?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Yes I get a successful install

Comment: did you repair permissions with disk utility as it says? Also does your package have the "require root privilege" flag enabled (ie the installer asks you to enter an admin's account and password)? I believe this flag is required if the package is supposed to run any scripts.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D its not working in update scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try a postflight script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# postflight script 
#

echo "My Scripts"

exit 0
```

Comment: what will be extension of the file?

Comment: Could be anything, but if you want to play it safe, give it an extension of "`.sh`".

Comment: you did "`chmod +x postinstall`", are the permissions also allowing read all? perhaps you should do "`chmod a+rx postinstall`".